# How to use custom props and theme with material-ui styled components API (Typescript)?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I'm attempting to use the Material UI styled components API to inject both a custom theme, and some props to a particular custom element.

I have either a custom theme or some props working, but not both together

#### Custom Theme

My custom theme is defined as follows in a separate file...

```
export interface ITheme extends Theme {
    sidebar: SideBarTheme;
}

type SideBarTheme = {
    // Various properties
};

const theme = createMuiTheme(
    {
        // Normal theme modifications
    },
    {
        sidebar: {
            // Custom theme modifications
        },
    } as ITheme
);
```

Which I then use with the Material-UI styled component API as follows....

```
const Profile = styled(Button)(({ theme }: { theme: ITheme }) => ({
    backgroundColor: theme.sidebar.profile.backgroundColor,
    paddingTop: 20,
    paddingBottom: 20
}));
```

This works fine within my jsx with `<Profile />`.

#### Props

For props I'm essentially using an exact copy of the example [here](https://material-ui.com/styles/basics/#adapting-the-styled-components-api)

```
interface MyButtonProps {
    color: string;
}

const Profile = styled( ({ color, ...other }: MyButtonProps & Omit<ButtonProps, keyof MyButtonProps>) => (
    <Button {...other} />
  ))({
    backgroundColor: (props: MyButtonProps) => props.color,
    paddingTop: 20,
    paddingBottom: 20
});
```

This works fine within my jsx when using `<Profile color="red"/>`

*How do I get both of these working together with typescript?*

I literally tried combining them like below but the props don't pass down...

```
const Profile = styled( ({ color, ...other }: MyButtonProps & Omit<ButtonProps, keyof MyButtonProps>) => (
    <Button {...other} />
  ))(({ theme }: { theme: ITheme }) => ({
    backgroundColor: (props: MyButtonProps) => props.color,
    color: theme.sidebar.profile.backgroundColor,
    paddingTop: 20,
    paddingBottom: 20
}));
```

Anything else I try just upsets TypeScript. The material-ui `styled` function is also too complicated for me to understand.

Many thanks,

Answer (score 9):

This problem has also almost drove me crazy, however I've managed to make it work with this approach:

```
import React from 'react'
import { styled, Theme, withTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles'
import { Box, BoxProps } from '@material-ui/core'

interface SidebarSectionProps {
  padded?: boolean
  theme: Theme
}

export const SidebarSectionComponent = styled(
  (props: SidebarSectionProps & BoxProps) => <Box {...props} />
)({
  marginBottom: ({ theme }: SidebarSectionProps) => theme.spacing(3),
  paddingLeft: ({ theme, padded }: SidebarSectionProps) =>
    padded ? theme.spacing(3) : 0,
  paddingRight: ({ theme, padded }: SidebarSectionProps) =>
    padded ? theme.spacing(3) : 0
})

export const SidebarSection = withTheme(SidebarSectionComponent)
```

Comment: FYI you can also access the theme within `styled` like so: `styled('div')(({theme}) => ({ backgroundColor: 'red' }))` (from [docs](https://mui.com/system/styled/#using-the-theme))

Answer (score 3):

For those who is using MUI5 and wondering how this could be done you can find an example in [this](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/29207#issuecomment-949283534) github comment from material ui.

Copy of Typescript example:

```
const StyledComp = styled("div", {
  shouldForwardProp: (prop) => prop !== "color" && prop !== 'myProp',
})<{ myProp?: boolean; color?: string }>(({ theme, myProp, color }) => ({
  backgroundColor: myProp ? "aliceblue" : "red",
  color,
  padding: theme.spacing(1)
}));

<StyledComp myProp color="red" /> // typed safe
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it makes sense to use styled-components or the material `styled` HOC because those are better for setting fixed styles which don't depend on Props.

But you can set the styles that you want on through the `style` prop of the `Button` component.

Here's a solution that seems to work:

```
interface AddedProps {
  theme: Theme;
  color: string;
};

type InnerProps = AddedProps & Omit<ButtonProps, keyof AddedProps>

const InnerProfile = ({color, theme, ...other}: InnerProps) => (
  <Button
    {...other}
    style={{
      ...other.style,
      paddingTop: 20,
      paddingBottom: 20,
      backgroundColor: color,
      color: (theme as MyTheme).sidebar?.profile?.backgroundColor,
    }}
  />
)

export const Profile = withTheme( InnerProfile );
```

We say that our `Profile` needs two `AddedProps`: the color and the theme.  We write `InnerProfile` assuming that those props exist.  Then in a separate step we apply the `withTheme` HOC so that the `theme` prop will be set.  The `color` prop is required and must be set by you when using `<Profile />`.

Now for this wonky craziness:

```
color: (theme as MyTheme).sidebar?.profile?.backgroundColor
```

What's happening is that `withTheme` knows that it injects *a theme* but it doesn't know that it injects *your specific theme* so typescript doesn't know that the theme has a property `sidebar` at all, since that's a custom property that you added.  You need to tell typescript "assume this theme has the properties of MyTheme" by doing `(theme as MyTheme)`.  You can get that type `MyTheme` by using `typeof` on the object where you created your custom theme.

Since I don't have access to your custom theme object, what I did was define an interface that has the needed property path, but with everything optional.  That looks like:

```
interface MyTheme extends Theme {
  sidebar?: {
    profile?: {
      backgroundColor?: string;
    } 
  }
}
```

And I used typescript `?.` notation when accessing `sidebar?.profile?.backgroundColor` to avoid the "object is possibly undefined" error.

Comment: Thanks, but it looks a little too verbose for my use case. I think I've found a way to achieve what I'm after by splitting off my custom element into it's own component and then passing props and theme into `makeStyles` within that component. Seems allot simpler than attempting to use `styled` for both. As you've suggested maybe `styled` is generally better suited for custom fixed styles.